# Convert between formats with different number of bits for exponent and fractional part

Tags: c, types, floating-point, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to refresh on floats. I am reading an exercise that asks to convert from format A having: k=3, 4 bits fraction and Bias=3 to format B having k=4, 3 bits fraction and Bias 7.
We should round when necessary.
Example between formats:

```
011 0000 (Value = 1)      =====> 0111 000 (Value = 1)  
010 1001 (Value = 25/32)  =====> 0110 100 (Value = 3/4 Rounded down)  
110 1111 (Value = 31/2)   =====> 1011 000 (Value = 16 Rounded up)
```

Problem: I can not figure out how the conversion works. First of all I managed to do it correctly in some case but my approach was to convert the bit pattern of format A to the decimal value and then to express that value in the bit pattern of format B.
But is there a way to somehow go from one bit pattern to the other without doing this conversion, just knowing that we extend the e by 1 bit and reduce the fraction by 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is there a way to somehow go from one bit pattern to the other without doing this conversion, just knowing that we extend the e by 1 bit and reduce the fraction by 1?

Yes, and this is much simpler than going through the decimal value (which is only correct if you convert to the exact decimal value and not an approximation).

```
011 0000 (Value = 1)   
  represents 1.0000 * 23-3
  is really 1.0 * 20 in “natural” binary
  represents 1.000 * 27-7 to pre-format for the destination format
   =====> 0111 000 (Value = 1)
```

Second example:

```
010 1001 (Value = 25/32)  
  represents 1.1001 * 22-3
  is really 1.1001 * 2-1
  rounds to 1.100 * 2-1 when we suppress one digit, because of “ties-to-even”
  is 1.100 * 26-7 pre-formated
=====> 0110 100 (Value = 3/4 Rounded down)
```

Third example:

```
110 1111 (Value = 31/2)
  represents 1.1111 * 26-3
  is really 1.1111 * 23
  rounds to 10.000 * 23 when we suppress one digit, because “ties-to-even” means “up” here and the carry propagates a long way
  renormalizes into 1.000 * 24
  is 1.000 * 211-7 pre-formated
   =====> 1011 000 (Value = 16 Rounded up)
```

Examples 2 and 3 are “halfway cases”. Well, rounding from 4-bit fractions to 3-bit fractions, 50% of examples will be halfway cases anyway.

In example 2, `1.1001` is as close to `1.100` as it is to `1.101`. So how is the result chosen? The one that is chosen is the one that ends with `0`. Here, `1.100`.

Comment: So what is the core idea?Trying to keep the same exponent power of 2? Or keep the same M? Could you give an example e.g. for `110 1111`? I mean I know hot to calculate the decimal value but I am getting lost on how to go from one format to the other

Comment: Thank you for the addition.The only part that I can not understand is the rounding part.E.g. `1.1001 * 2-1 rounds to 1.100 * 2-1 when we suppress one digit`. Why? If we round to 3 bits after the decimal point the 4th bit is 1. So why don't we round up to 1.001? Same for `rounds to 1.1111 * 2^3`. The 4th bit after the decimal is a 1 so why not have 1.111? I am not clear on how we do the rounding part

Comment: @Cratylus Examples 2 and 3 are halfway cases. Well, rounding from 4-bit fractions to 3-bit fractions, 50% of examples will be “halfway cases” anyway. 1.1001 is as close to 1.100 as it is to 1.101. So how is the result chosen? The one that is chosen is the one that ends with a 0. Here, 1.100.

Comment: I see. And for 1.1111? We can't go to 1.110 because it is smaller and we add a 1 that carries over?

Comment: @Cratylus To round 1.1111 to 3 binary digits after the dot, the choices are 1.111 and 10.000, which are the two numbers that it is in-between. The latter is the “even” one because it ends in 0.

Comment: One more question if you have time for me. In the case of:`000 0001` where it is `2^-2 *(0.0001)` (due to being de-normalized) we get in the rounding `2^-2*(0.000)` and this is equal to 0 and we start to increase the e? I am not sure how each step follows the next to end up with (1/64) formally