# Casting from double to float

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, double, bit-manipulation

I was reading that `d == (double)(float)d` where d is a `double` will not evaluate to true.
It makes sense because we are casting to a type of lower precision but *I can not understand the number given as an example.
It was if d is `1e40` the expression will evaluate to +infinity
But the bit pattern of `1e40` is:

```
1110101100011001010011111000111000011010111001010010010111111101010111011100111110101011000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

And the infinity is represented by the exponent all 1s and the fraction all 0s.
So how will casting reduce this specific example to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum `float` (IEEE-754 `binary32`) value is approximately `3.4028234 × 1e38`. So when `double` value `1e40` is converted to `float` it yields positive infinity.

Comment: So it is not a matter of "cutting" of part of the bit pattern to end up with the bit pattern that represents infinity?Like with integers where when we cast part of the bit pattern is preserved

Comment: @Cratylus For signed integers, the behavior you describe (e.g., in `signed char x = 256;`) is actually implementation-defined in C. For floating points, IEEE-754 with the default rounding mandates the result is positive infinity here.

Comment: This answer makes it sound like the reasoning “X is larger than the maximum [finite] float value therefore X rounds to the float `+inf`” applies. This line of reasoning is wrong, although it works for `1e40`. The smallest number to round to the float `+inf` is exactly, in hexadecimal, 0x1.ffffffp127, or approximately, in decimal, 3.4028235678E38.

Comment: @PascalCuoq *This line of reasoning is wrong, although it works for 1e40.* Could you elaborate a little bit? Any counterexample to show?

Comment: “3.4028235677E38f” is a counter-example. It rounds to `FLT_MAX` but is definitely larger than “3.4028234 × 1e38”.

Comment: @PascalCuoq  3.4028235677E38f is not larger than the largest `float` finite value, so it is not a counterexample. I put `3.4028234 × 1e38` in my answer as an approximation of the largest `float` value but it is definitely not the largest finite `float` value. Any other counterexample?

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I meant: `3.4028235677E38f` is a counter example because 3.4028235677 × 10^38 is definitely larger than 3.4028234 × 10^38.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Still 3.4028235677E38 is less than the maximum `float` finite value and rounds with default rounding to the largest `float` finite value. Again for `3.4028234 × 10^38` I put it as an approximation sorry if it was not clear.

Comment: I don't know if you mean “3.4028235677E38” to be a `double` or a decimal number, but either way, it is definitely **not** less than the maximum `float` finite value, which is, as you say, approximately 3.4028234 × 10^38.

Comment: @PascalCuoq You said *This answer makes it sound like the reasoning *"X is larger than the maximum [finite] float value therefore X rounds to the float +inf” applies."* I still don't know why this would be wrong. For me it is correct and ruled by *(IEEE-754-2008, 7.4 Overflow) "[...] roundTiesToEven and roundTiesToAway carry all overflows to ∞ with the sign of the intermediate
result."*

Comment: To put it differently, the implication “X is larger than D, the decimal representation of `FLT_MAX` therefore X rounds to `+inf` as a `float`” is wrong even if you use for “D” the **exact** decimal representation of FLT_MAX, 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.

Comment: @Ouah I don't have access to the IEEE 754 standard, but I am convinced that in this sentence, “overflow” only describes the situation where the value would round to a normalized value that uses the first non-representable exponent (128). Half the values between FLT_MAX (0x1.fffffep127) and the smallest value with the forbidden exponent (0x1.0p128) round down to FLT_MAX despite being larger than it. The exact limit is 0x1.ffffffp127 which, because of the “ties to even” rule, rounds to +inf. It is the smallest value to do so.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I don't disagree with that but I think for the sake of OP question it is simpler to just say that with default IEEE-754 rounding a number larger than the largest float finite number is rounded to +inf. It is not complete for the values you are referring to but it is enough to answer OP question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq And sorry contrary with I said in one previous comment you were right with `3.4028235677e38f` (I misread it) being a correct counterexample: it is larger that the largest normal `float` value but after conversion it is converted to the largest normal `float` value and not `+inf` in roundTiesToEven.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that this may be undefined behavior depending on whether `float` supports positive and negative infinity. N1570 §6.3.1.5:

> When a value of real floating type is converted to a real floating
>   type, if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the
>   new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the
>   range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented
>   exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower
>   representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner. If
>   the value being converted is outside the range of values that can be
>   represented, the behavior is undefined.

§5.2.4.2.2/p5:

> The minimum range of representable values for a floating type is the
>   most negative finite floating-point number representable in that type
>   through the most positive finite floating-point number representable in
>   that type. In addition, if negative infinity is representable in a
>   type, the range of that type is extended to all negative real numbers;
>   likewise, if positive infinity is representable in a type, the range
>   of that type is extended to all positive real numbers.

If IEEE-754 floating point is used, then `1e40` is outside the range of representable finite numbers of `binary32`, and the conversion yields positive infinity in default rounding mode.

Comment: So it is not a matter of "cutting" of part of the bit pattern to end up with the bit pattern that represents infinity?Like with integers where when we cast part of the bit pattern is preserved

Comment: It's worth noting that *worth nothing* is not the same as *worth noting*.

Comment: @barakmanos It is worth noting that *worth nothing* has been changed to *worth noting*.

Comment: @Cratylus No, it doesn't "cut", so to speak. (Even with integers, if the value isn't representable in the destination type, the result is implementation-defined - so it's not required to "cut".)

Comment: @T.C. IEEE-754 mandates the result is positive infinity here in the default rounding (*roundTiesToEven* rounding-direction).

Comment: The representable range of binary32 goes from -inf to +inf. 1e40 is not outside of this range, so the behavior is not undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to convert the binary sequence in your question to `float`, the next step after writing it in binary will be to “normalize” it so:

```
1.11010110001100101001111100011100001101011100101001001011111110… * 2128
```

And after rounding to 24 significant digits:

```
1.11010110001100101010000 * 2128
```

The number 128 is outside the acceptable range for exponents for the single-precision IEEE 754 binary representation. Exponents for normalized numbers go from -126 to +127, with a couple of exceptional values used to represent denomalized numbers (including 0), infinities and NaN.

This is why the number 1E38 ends up represented, as a `float`, as `+inf`, one of the special values encoded with one of the special exponents, and does not have the significand 1.110101100011… that you could have expected.

Comment: +1.This answer the way it is phrased is very interesting as it seems to somehow "touch" my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831471/convert-between-formats-with-different-number-of-bits-for-exponent-and-fractiona

Comment: How did you derive 2^128? I assume the rounding on 24 digits is because the float's fractional part is 24 (23+1)?

Comment: 128 is the number of binary digits I put to the left of the dot when normalizing. Same thing as 111 = 11.1 * 2^1 = 1.11 * 2^2. 128 is a forbidden exponent because allowed exponents for normalized binary32 numbers go from -126 to 127. In other words, the off-limitness of 128 comes from the choice of 8 bits of exponent and the need to reserve two exponents for special values. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format